# Converting string to float in Fluentd

Tags: fluentd

my head has been spinning for the past two days for this seemed simple task... I'm new to Fluentd.
The data comes in JSON, with perfect key and value form. I use td-agent3.

{"key1":"value1","key2":"*number_in_string*"}

```
#td-agent.conf
<source>
  @type tcp
  port 24224
  tag test
  bind 0.0.0.0
  <parse>
    @type json
    types key2:float
  </parse>
</source>

<match **>
  @type copy
  #store locally
  <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/test.log
  </store>
</match>
```

I get *pattern not match* result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I abandoned my original method entirely. I am using *fluent-plugin-filter_typecast* instead. That works!